# Verification of $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{7n - i}{3n^2 - ni - 2 - i}$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, limits

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{7n - i}{3n^2 - ni - 2 - i}$$

I used L'hopital rule to get it down to $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{7}{5n} = 0$$

Would this be true?

Comment: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{7}{5n} = \frac 75\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac 1n = \frac 75\times 0 = 0.$$ Looks true to me, however, this is true for all denominators $cn$. By using l^Hôpital’s rule, you should not have $c = 5$, although the limit *is* true. I would have provided a proper answer but I am a bit too late. Look down below $\downarrow$

Comment: Did you prove a complex version of l'Hospital in class?

Comment: @mickep yes I did

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $i$ is constant (independent of $n$), then yes: the limit is $0$.

I'm not sure how you got $5n$ in the denominator by applying l'Hôpital though, I would expect:

$$\frac{\mbox{d}}{\mbox{d}n}\left(3n^2-ni-2-i\right)=6n-i$$

Answer (score 0):

In this case it can be done a lot simpler than L'Hopital. (*Can* you apply l'Hopital if the limit is over integers? Is the limit over integers?). Divide both the numerator and the denominator by $n^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Your expression behaves like
$$\frac{7}{3n}$$
for large $n$.